# Unrecognized selector sent to instance on if(bool)

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I know this questions has been posted a lot, but they are all very specific and do not apply to my problem.

> [MirrorStarAV startRecording:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15561d60

I get this error when calling the following method:

```
- (bool) startRecording {
    bool result = NO;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!_recording) { //Exception is raised on this line
            result = [self setUpWriter];
            startedAt = [[NSDate date] retain];
            _recording = YES;
         }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I call the method as following:

```
bool _startRecording(){
    return [delegateMSA startRecording];
}
```

Comment: in which class startRecording: present? your delegate pointing to MirrorStarAV instance.

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: check startRecording method  in .h and .m  properly in class of MirrorStarAV object, check also whether it has input parameter or not

Comment: Note that if you implement both setter and getter of `recording` property, than you also MUST synthesize it in you class `@synthesize recording;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[MirrorStarAV startRecording:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15561d60
```

The above error message is basically saying that `MirrorStarAV` doesn't respond to `startRecording:` so when you call `[delegateMSA startRecording];` it is crashing. The `delegateMSA` has an instance of `MirrorStarAV` set to it but instances of `MirrorStarAV` don't respond to `` `startRecording: ``

Whilst **YES** it would be better for you to change your method to something like

```
bool _startRecording(){
    if ([delegateMSA respondsToSelector:@selector(startRecording)])
    {
        return [delegateMSA startRecording];
    }
    return false;
}
```

but this isn't your issue. Note that `[MirrorStarAV startRecording:]` has a colon `:` at the end. You are calling `startRecording:` somewhere over `startRecording`

Comment: I've fixed the problem sort of thanks to this. The problem was not in the library itself but it seems like a bug in xCode.
I found out it was giving me a debug I had commented out. Apparently when I rebuild my library it was not building anymore and I kept using my old .a file, while I had updated my header file. Because of this my library was calling to a method with a parameter that did not exist.
So the recording works now, but the recorded video is all black. You guys have any quick solutions I can try or shall I open a new question?

Comment: OK that makes sense. So basically when you provided a new build of your library the version that your project was linking to wasn't updated??? Just as a side note, no one would have got that since you make no reference to a library, not that it matters that much as we have given enough information for you to solve it yourself.

Comment: Exactly, and it was even worse then that. The actual .a file I would receive after building my library was not getting updates at all after building. In this library it was still calling the debugs I had removed long before... Guess this does explain why I was stuck :)

Comment: Well as long as you have sorted it that is the important thing.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the delegateMSA is an instance of class where you have the startRecording method.

Or do something like

```
bool _startRecording(){
   if([delegateMSA respondsToSelector:@selector(startRecording)]) {
       return [delegateMSA startRecording];
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not certain you are answering the question, but much better is to use `respondsToSelector` anyway (the class shouldn't have to know about its delegate, just the interface of the delegate).

Answer (score 0):

Check before, whether the delegate responds to this method, so you can make sure that the object is also able to respond to this selector:

```
bool _startRecording(){
    if ([delegateMSA respondsToSelector:@selector(startRecording)])
    {
        return [delegateMSA startRecording];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Either way, I would recommend to add this selector to the delegates methods with @required:

```
@protocol MyRecorderDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (BOOL)startRecording;

@end
```

So, you would get a compiler warning, if your delegate was not implementing this method.

Comment: That method is only right if you assume that sometimes you have delegates that respond to the method, and sometimes you don't, and each is correct. It looks to me that the method is expected to always be there, and if it isn't, that's a bug that needs fixing, not hiding.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this is why I mentioned the aspect to set the method as required for the protocol. So a compiler warning could guide him to the correct line